# Finding $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\left(\frac{1-\sin x}{(\pi-2x)^4}\right)(\cos x)(8x^3 - \pi^3)$ using algebra of limits

Tags: calculus

Let $$
F(x) = \left(\frac{1-\sin x}{(\pi-2x)^4}\right)(\cos x)(8x^3 - \pi^3)
$$ 
Then find the limit of $F(x)$ as $x$ tends to $\pi/2$.

How can we find the limit using algebra of limits?

The limit of $\dfrac{1-\sin x}{(\pi-2x)^4}$ as $x$ tends to $\pi/2$ is some non-zero finite number. And the limit of rest part is zero. Then why the limit of the whole function is not $0$?

The limit of $F(x)$ is $-\frac{3\pi^2}{16}$.

How to apply algebra of limits here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit of $\frac{1-\sin x}{(\pi-2x)^4}$ as $x$ tends to $\pi/2$ is NOT some non zero finite number.

Note that $(8x^3 - \pi^3)=(2x-\pi)(4x^2+2x\pi+\pi^2)$, then 
$$F(x)=\frac{1-\sin x}{(2x-\pi)^2}\cdot\frac{\cos x}{(2x-\pi)}\cdot (4x^2+2x\pi+\pi^2)$$
Now evaluate the limit of each factor. This time they are all finite numbers and we can apply the rule related to your previous question [How to apply algebra of limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013929/how-to-apply-algebra-of-limits)

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

Make life simpler using $x=y+\frac \pi 2$ which makes
$$\lim_{x\to\frac \pi2}\left(\frac{1-\sin (x)}{(\pi-2x)^4}\right)\cos (x)(8x^3 - \pi^3)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\left(4 y^2+6 \pi  y+3 \pi ^2\right) \sin (y) (\cos (y)-1)}{8 y^3}$$ Now, use the usual Taylor the series and you will get
$$\frac{\left(4 y^2+6 \pi  y+3 \pi ^2\right) \sin (y) (\cos (y)-1)}{8 y^3}=-\frac{3 \pi ^2}{16}-\frac{3 \pi  y}{8}+O\left(y^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Answer (score 1):

Because we are dealing with an indeterminate form $0\cdot \infty$ and algebraic theorems do not apply.

To solve the limit let $y=\pi/2-x\to 0$ then

$$\frac{1-\sin x}{(\pi-2x)^4}\cos x(8x^3 - \pi^3)=-\frac{1-\cos y}{16y^4}8y\sin y \left((\pi/2-y)^2+(\pi/2-y)\pi/2+(\pi/2)^2\right)=$$

$$=-\frac{1-\cos y}{2y^2}\frac{\sin y}y \left((\pi/2-y)^2+(\pi/2-y)\pi/2+(\pi/2)^2\right)$$

Comment: I didn't get this indeterminate form. Can you please explain.

Comment: What about the limit of $\frac{(1-\sin x}{(pi-2x)^4}$?

Comment: Oh, it is infinity. I made mistake in finding this one. Thanks.